# Как сделать чтобы кнопка оставалась активной (зажатой или с hover) пока пользователь не нажмет другую? чтобы было понятно какой адрес выбран сейчас?

Tags: jquery, css3

```js
function HomeControl(controlDiv, map) {

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(zoomout, 'click', function() {
    var currentZoomLevel = map.getZoom();
    if (currentZoomLevel != 0) {
      map.setZoom(currentZoomLevel - 1);
    }
  });

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(zoomin, 'click', function() {
    var currentZoomLevel = map.getZoom();
    if (currentZoomLevel != 21) {
      map.setZoom(currentZoomLevel + 1);
    }
  });
}


function initialize() {
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
  var myLatlng = {
    lat: 50.5065401,
    lng: 30.5840678
  };
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: myLatlng,
    Marker: true,
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);

  var locations = [
    ['Oliver1', 52.231871, 21.005841],
    ['Oliver2', 50.509616, 30.7880527],
  ];

  var marker, i;
  var Oliver1 = document.getElementById("Oliver1");
  var Oliver2 = document.getElementById("Oliver2");
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  Oliver1.addEventListener("click", function() {
    map.setZoom(15);
    map.setCenter({
      lat: 50.5065401,
      lng: 30.5840678
    });
  });

  Oliver2.addEventListener("click", function() {
    map.setZoom(15);
    map.setCenter({
      lat: 50.509616,
      lng: 30.7880527
    });
  });


  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
        map.setZoom(15);
        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
      }
    })(marker, i));


    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
        map.setZoom(15);
        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
      }
    })(marker, i));

  }
  var homeControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
  var homeControl = new HomeControl(homeControlDiv, map);
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', HomeControl);
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
#map {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 580px;
  height: 340px;
}

#places {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
}

#Oliver1:hover {
  color: green;
}

#Oliver2:hover {
  color: green;
}

.places__place {
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  background: #e67e22;
  border: 0;
  font-style: Arial;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #da751c;
  border-radius: 14px;
  opacity: 0.9;
  cursor: pointer;
  &:hover {
    background: #d35400;
  }
}

.places__place {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <div id="places">
    <div class="places__place" id="Oliver1"><span>Oliver1</span></div>
    <div class="places__place" id="Oliver2"><span>Oliver2</span></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае только js
при клике отменяете класс, у ненужных, ну и соответственно добавляйте там где нужно
Общая конструкция на jquery

```
$('#places').on('click', '.places__place', function(){
   $('.places__place').removeClass('hover');

    $(this).addClass('hover');
 })
```

или в Oliver1.addEventListener("click", function()  добавить

```
Oliver1.classList.add('hover')
Oliver2.classList.remove('hover')
```

Соответственно в Oliver2.addEventListener("click", function()  добавить

```
Oliver1.classList.remove('hover')
Oliver2.classList.add('hover')
```

так:

```
 Oliver1.addEventListener("click", function() {
  map.setZoom(15);
  map.setCenter({
    lat: 50.5065401,
    lng: 30.5840678
  });

  Oliver1.classList.add('hover')
  Oliver2.classList.remove('hover')
});

Oliver2.addEventListener("click", function() {
  map.setZoom(15);
  map.setCenter({
    lat: 50.509616,
    lng: 30.7880527
  });

  Oliver1.classList.remove('hover')
  Oliver2.classList.add('hover')
});
```

Comment: Прошу прощения, так должна выглядеть:

Comment: Oliver1.addEventListener("click", function () {
        map.setZoom(15);
        map.setCenter({
            lat: 50.5065401,
            lng: 30.5840678
     });
        Oliver1.classList.add('hover');
 Oliver2.classList.remove('hover')
    });

Comment: Отредактировал запись, в общий код

Comment: на класс hover, повести те же стили
.places__place:hover,
.places__place.hover {}

Comment: Что то не работает(

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EQXaNP

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pawvdM
приведите свои стили в порядок, у вас цвет задаётся каждому DIV отдельно,на ховер, а фон по классу. перенесите  стили (цвет и фон) в одно место, на класс places__place

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Все получилось))